# hyperlink to retrieve data from a database in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am developing job portal which displays different jobs stored in database (SQL Server). I am using ASP.NET and HTML.

I have `job_title` and `unique job_id` in database table. I have created hyperlink for `job_title` which is retrieved from database. Now I want to display the details of that particular job on a different page by clicking `job_title` of that job.

I need `job_id` for that particular job whose details I want to display on next hyper linked page. The reason for not to use `job_title` instead of `job_id` is that `job_title` is not unique, but `job_id` is. Please tell me how to accomplish that or if you have another solution?

Here is some sample code for this:

(jobs.aspx)

```
      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:JobPortalConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [job_title], [description] FROM [jobs]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
      <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
          <AlternatingItemTemplate>
              <strong>Job Title:</strong>
              <span style="">
              <asp:Label ID="job_titleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("job_title") %>' />
              <br />
              <strong>Description:</strong>
              <asp:Label ID="descriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("description") %>' />
              <br />
              <br />
              </span>
          </AlternatingItemTemplate>
          <EditItemTemplate>
              <span style="">job_title:
              <asp:TextBox ID="job_titleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("job_title") %>' />
              <br />
              description:
              <asp:TextBox ID="descriptionTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("description") %>' />
              <br />
              <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
              <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
              <br /><br /></span>
          </EditItemTemplate>
          <EmptyDataTemplate>
              <span>No data was returned.</span>
          </EmptyDataTemplate>
          <InsertItemTemplate>
              <span style="">job_title:
              <asp:TextBox ID="job_titleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("job_title") %>' />
              <br />description:
              <asp:TextBox ID="descriptionTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("description") %>' />
              <br />
              <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
              <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />
              <br /><br /></span>
          </InsertItemTemplate>
          <ItemTemplate>
              <strong>Job Title:</strong>
              <span style="">
              <asp:Label ID="job_titleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("job_title") %>'></asp:Label>
              <br />
              <strong>Description:</strong>
              <asp:Label ID="descriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("description") %>'></asp:Label>
              <br />  
              <br/>
              </span>
          </ItemTemplate>
          <LayoutTemplate>
              <div id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" style="">
                  <span runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
                  &nbsp;</span></div>
              <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Height="30px" OnClick="Button1_Click1" Text="Apply Now" Width="100px" />
              <div style="">
                  <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server">
                      <Fields>
                          <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
                          <asp:NumericPagerField />
                          <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowLastPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
                      </Fields>
                  </asp:DataPager>
              </div>
          </LayoutTemplate>
          <SelectedItemTemplate>
              <span style="">job_title:
              <asp:Label ID="job_titleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("job_title") %>' />
              <br />
              description:
              <asp:Label ID="descriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("description") %>' />
              <br />
```

```
  </div>
```

Comment: Best to show some sample code.   Really not sure if you need help with SQL, ASP.Net?

Comment: I have added code of .aspx page please check it....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you wanna have urls like this:

```
blabla-your-website.com/fisrt-job-title
blabla-your-website.com/second-job-title
blabla-your-website.com/other-job-title
```

But you said:

> job_title is not unique, but job_id is

So it's not possible to do. The common solution for this is to use ids and titles at the same time in your url:

```
blabla-your-website.com/1-fisrt-job-title
blabla-your-website.com/22-second-job-title
blabla-your-website.com/333-other-job-title
```

Where 1, 22, and 333 are unique ids for particular job.

If your titles are unique, it's quite easy to do. Take a look at [RacoonBlog's SlugConverter](https://github.com/ayende/RaccoonBlog/blob/master/RaccoonBlog.Web/Infrastructure/Common/SlugConverter.cs). It is used to convert your titles to urls like this (code from RacoonBlog tests):

```
        var result = SlugConverter.TitleToSlug("Document based modeling: Auctions & Bids");
        Assert.Equal("document-based-modeling-auctions-bids", result);

        result = SlugConverter.TitleToSlug("Hiring Questions–The phone book");
        Assert.Equal("hiring-questions-the-phone-book", result);
```