# How to hyperlink to retrieve data from database in ASP.NET (with C#)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am developing job portal which displays different jobs stored in a SQL Server database. I am using ASP.NET and HTML.

I have `job_title` and unique `job_id` in my database table. I have created a hyperlink for `job_title` which is retrieved from database. Now I want to display the details of that particular job on a different page by clicking `job_title` of that job.

I need `job_id` for that particular job whose details I want to display on next hyper linked page. The reason for not to use `job_title` instead of `job_id` is that `job_title` is not unique, but `job_id` is.

Please tell me how to accomplish that or if you have another solution?

Comment: pass it via querystring

Comment: We use querystring basically to transfer data from one page to other page just like as session but how to retrieve job_id from table for that particular job_title hyperlink?

Comment: @user3151301 when you have [already asked a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870142/hyperlink-to-retrieve-data-from-a-database-in-asp-net), there is no need to ask it again. If you aren't getting the answers you want, then edit the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You include the value in the query string of the URL.

**WebForms**:

Something like this:

```
<a href="JobDetails.aspx?jobID=123">Click here for details</a>
```

Then in `JobDetails.aspx` you would get the value in `Page_Load` like this:

```
var jobID = Request.QueryString["jobID"];
```

Note that the value would be a string, so you'd need to parse it to a numeric type in order to properly use it.  `int.TryParse()` can help with that.

**MVC**:

Something like this:

```
<a href="/Job/Details/123">Click here for details</a>
```

Then in the `Details` action you would have a parameter for the `id` value:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    // Code to get job details and return a View
}
```